# How to customize Default text on browser close event

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

When we close the browser, we get a notification saying "some custom text" and "leave this page" and "stay on this page".

I am using below code to handle such scenario

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert(hook); // hook is an indicator which is allowing me to get notification only on click of browser's [X] button not on other submit buttons or links
    if (hook) {
       return "Did you save your stuff?" // this is equal to "some custom text"
    }
}
```

So my question is, how to avoid "leave this page" and "stay on this page" options. 
I do not want these notification options.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple actually..... If you do not return anything from method it wont show anything. 
i.e

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  alert("any message");             
  if (hook) {
     // my functionality
  }
}
```